# Requesting help identifying potential damaged resistor on PCB

Tags: pcb, resistors, damage

The picture is a motor control board which recently failed. The digital console indicates some problem communicating with the motor. Inconsistent power supply and moisture MAY have played a factor. Not sure.

Also worth mentioning I'm a dangerous beginner at this. But I'm too stubborn to buy an expensive replacement control board when I stand a chance of repairing this one. So far I've tested health of the motor and control wires via multimeter. This control board remains a suspect just by process of elimination. The white coating there stands out on an otherwise clean PCB.

To be clear my questions are:

1. In your expert opinion do you see any potential damage?
2. If this is damage, how fixable does it seem? Would it be sensible/worthwhile to replace that resistor and reassemble and test the unit?

[image: pcb]

Comment: You may clean with contaminants with Q tip and IPA alcohal, measure R168

Comment: So what I'm hearing from you is that this doesn't look like burnout, more just like some gunk that somehow got there.

Comment: R22, ZD6 and Q6 look unhealthy also

Comment: Resolution is too low to tell what it is. Can you provide a closer view?

Comment: After you clean with Isopropanol Alcohol, you can better examine the resistor and the surrounding PCB.  IME you'll find the 'gunk' is copper 'rust' and the PCB pad around that resistor is gone (dissolved).  You'll also likely not be able to solder to the resistor as it's lead would have all it's plating stripped away.   Some good magnification helps here immensely.   Get a new resistor and replace it ('rebuilding' the rotted PCB connection of course).     You might get lucky   ;)

Comment: Maybe it got wet or that big fat electrolytic cap beside it leaked. Resistors don’t generally ooze fluids.

Comment: It is hard to say from this picture, anyway it seems the PCB has some conformal coating which protects from moisture. This is rather normal when looking at the motor drives, they are working in harsh environments often. Also, this coating will be in your way when you try to solder. It is recommended to remove coating before going to soldering, preferably by (delicate) sandblasting.